# Copy a file in ubuntu to windows using putty - ssh from windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, putty, file-copying

I Have to copy a .csv file in my ubuntu machine into my windows machine by standing in windows itself. That is I have to do the copying process by running putty or anything like that from windows machine. I need it as a command because I have to do it with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) program from Java:

```
String[] command = {
    "pscp",
    "-q", // quiet, don't show statistics
    "-pw", // passw login with specified password
    "yourP4ssw0rd", // the user password
    "username@yourhost:file.csv", 
    "c:\\the\\destination\\of\\your\\file.csv"
};

// command == pscp -q -pw yourP4ssw0rd username@yourhost:file.csv c:\\the\\destination\\of\\your\\file.csv
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = 
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}

...
```

#### Reference

- [PSCP manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter5.html)
- [Download PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: Could you please mention the details of parameters also in the answer..And where will I mention the source(in ubuntu) and destination(in windows) of csv file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. It helped me a lot.. Good way of answering :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). It provides a Java API to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("putty -ssh -2 -P 22 USERNAME@SERVER_ADDR -pw PASS -m command.txt");
p.waitFor();

BufferedReader reader = 
     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention the parameters also in the answer.. I mean -2 -P 22 etc. And where will I mention the csv file I have to copy from Ubuntu.

Comment: And where will I mention the source(in ubuntu) and destination(in windows) of csv file.